# Powershell with regular expression and delete operation

Tags: regex, powershell, delete-file

I have a set of backup files, like **ABC20200216.bak**, **ABC20200217.bak** etc. They all follow this pattern: **ABCYYYYMMDD.bak**

I have a Windows batch script which deleted all my backup files older than 15 days. This works like magic:

`forfiles /p "C:\DB Backup" /m ABC????????.bak /D -15 /C "cmd /c del @path"`

But I want to make a change so my backup on each 1st day of the month does not get deleted. So I want to exclude all files **ABCYYYYMM01.bak** from above script.

I got to know that I need to use Powershell because forfiles does not support regular expressions and I think I'll need regexp to write this.

The max I could do to get a file list using Powershell:
`powershell "dir 'C:\DB Backup' | ?{ $_.Name -match 'ABC[0-9]{8}.*' } | select Name"`

But I don't really know regular expressions, so please help me with a regular expression to exclude files ending in **01.bak**.

Plus I don't know how to combine the above Powershell and a delete operation. Can I get some help with this also, please?

Comment: `.*` at the end should be replaced with `.*$(?<!01\.bak)`

Comment: This help me to get the list of the files the way I want, thanks for that. But there was a second question also: how to combine this list with a delete operation so I can delete the listed files. This second question remained unanswered.

Comment: But I finally found the solution:

```powershell "dir 'C:\DB Backup' | ?{ $_.Name -match 'ABC[0-9]{8}.bak$(?<!13.bak)' } | foreach { $_.Delete() }"```